# Error creating user in ODOO v16 (self hosted) with Zapier

Tags: odoo, zapier

I am trying to create a user via a zapier integration and get the following error:

Fault (code warning -- UserError The operation cannot be completed: - Create/update: a mandatory field is not set. - Delete: another model requires the record being deleted. If possible, archive it instead. Model: User (res.users) Field: Company (company_id) ) occurred. Message:

I have searched via forums for a prior response that refers to the database rule or logic that refers to the company_id and res.users about what to do to solve the constraint. I have tried changing field inputs to solve the requirement for the company_id as to whether its new, existing or updated - I just don't know.

Any help would be most appreciated.